# Can I build swift files only in react native project using XCode?

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to build swift native module in React Native project. Whenever I try build to test that module, it takes too much time(2~3 minutes) while it takes only 20 seconds in pure swift project. Is there any way to build and test only swift files in React native project using xCode? Or is there any better way to test swift module written in react native project?

I've tested the same code in pure swift project in another repository and after test I copy & pasted that code to react native repo.